# How can I start programming with quickly

Tags: quickly

I downloaded quickly from software centre as described in http://developer.ubuntu.com 
and I started making apps from the tutorial but it seems that those apps aren't working.
Can you help me:-)

Comment: Please be more specific on what the problem is, check [this introduction video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
quickly create MyProgram 

cd MyProgram

quickly run
```

This should bring up the default GUI interface of your program.

If it does not then there is something wrong with your installation. Try re installing it

[QUICKLY how to use: Tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/)